# Changing the UITableViewCell swipe action title

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitableviewrowaction

I have a row action button titled "Activate". When I press it, I want the title to change to "Deactivate".

[image]

I was unable to change the title in the handler function. Also, "Activate" and "Deactivate" should have different functions.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    let account = accountTypes[indexPath.section].accounts[indexPath.row]

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
        // action delete
    })

    let activation = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Activate", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
        // action activate
    })
    activation.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    let arrayofactions: Array = [delete, activation]
    return arrayofactions
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manage your cell's state manually for each indexpath when you want to show activate and de-activate.
Save data(condition) for individual **indexpath** and put below condition in your **editActionsForRowAtIndexPath** method.

```
let arrayofactions
if(condition true) {
  let activation = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Activate", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
    // action activate
  })
   activation.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
   arrayofactions: Array = [delete, activation]
}
else {
   let deactivation = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "De-Activate", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
    // action deactivate
  })
   deactivation.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
   deactivation: Array = [delete, deactivation]

}
```

Comment: Yes this is perfect, thanks dude. I should have thought of this!!